# SQL Wrong Result Values On Money Sum

Tags: sql, delphi

Using Delphi X10 & Absolute Database SQL92 Compatible.
I am using this SQL script :

```
  SELECT SUM (CREDIT) AS "SUM_CREDIT",
         SUM (DEBIT) AS "SUM_DEBIT",
         SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT) AS Balance,
         YearPay,
         IDCustomer,
         DescCredit
    FROM CostumersPayments
GROUP BY YearPay, IDCustomer, DescCredit
  HAVING (SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT)) > 0
ORDER BY YearPay;
```

My table has about 3000 records; the returned result is about 300 records.

The problem is that I get for equal debit with equal credit, balance as 0

Result:

```
Credit | Debit  | Balance
$ 4,56 | $ 4,56 |    0
$12,12 | $12,12 |    0
$21,6  | $21,6  |    0
.....
```

This happens for about 30 result records, the others result records are ok.

This is a strange behavior because I want `HAVING (SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT)) > 0`. So after searching a little I have found that when `AS FLOAT` converting:

```
         CAST(SUM (CREDIT) AS FLOAT) AS "SUM_CREDIT",
         CAST(SUM (DEBIT) AS FLOAT) AS "SUM_DEBIT",
         CAST(SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT) AS FLOAT) AS "SUM_BALANCE"
```

The returned results for the 30 same records after the conversion are:

```
Credit | Debit  | Balance
$ 4,56 | $ 4,56 | 8,88178419700125E-16
$12,12 | $12,12 | 1,77635683940025E-15
$21,6  | $21,60 | 3,5527136788005E-15
```

In most Balance result the values are 3,5527136788005E-15 and 7,105427357601E-15. The resulting 0's have values 0,000something. I have found the records and retype the debit & credit values. Same result.

The field types are Currency on the Table.

Where is the problem?

Comment: FLOAT doesn't look much like currency. Are you sure the arithmetic is decimal rather than binary?

Comment: All my Fields are Currency, what do you mean binary? The Float Conversion was only for test. My real code was the 1st one on the top of my post.

Thanks David

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it returns those values, but a quick fix around would be to discard all those garbage decimals when checking if CREDIT - DEBIT = 0.

```
 SELECT SUM (CREDIT) AS "SUM_CREDIT",
         SUM (DEBIT) AS "SUM_DEBIT",
         SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT) AS Balance,
         YearPay,
         IDCustomer,
         DescCredit
    FROM CostumersPayments
GROUP BY YearPay, IDCustomer, DescCredit
  HAVING cast(SUM (CREDIT) - SUM (DEBIT) as numeric(18, 4)) > 0
ORDER BY YearPay;
```